# filtering by alphabetical order - vuejs, axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I already have a filter that filters by brand name. I now want to filter these results by alphabetical order through "product.name". Below is my axios functions.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      filteredProducts: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
 axios
 .get('/src/stores/sneakers.json')
 .then(response => (this.filteredProducts = response.data))
  },

  computed: {
    resultCount () {
            return Object.keys(this.filteredList).length
        },
    filteredList(){
            return this.filteredProducts.filter(product => 
            product.brand.includes(this.brand?.name)
      )
        }
    },
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean sort by alphabetical order? If so take a look at the `sort()` function in javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sort method to sort the array of objects by the name property.

```js
this.filteredProducts.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.name < b.name) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.name > b.name) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});
```